# Always get HttpError 404 by change IDs of push notifications when uploading zip, rar, tar.gz to Google Drive

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-drive-api

The problem is that I never get the information from Google Drive notifications when uploading zip, rar, tar.gz, etc. Every time my web application gets a change ID from push notifications, it will use it to query information by Google Drive API and then receive the message "HttpError 404 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/changes/xxxx?alt=json returned "Change not found: xxxx""  (xxxx means number)

Therefore I refined my flow and then make our application query the last three change IDs when receiving notifications. For instance, when the application gets the change ID 1211, it also queries the Change ID 1210 and 1209 through Google Drive API. It cannot query too many previous change ID because the previous change ID that is less than 5 usually means another different change. The application indeed could get information of changed files from the second change ID from the last one.

But my application could get information from the last change ID immediately if users upload txt files.

Is there anything I misunderstood?

Thanks a million

Comment: Vote and comment on this bug please: https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3706

Comment: Hey! skav, I star it already. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A change made to a file is invalidated by a subsequent change to the file.

Lets say you have change #100, and get a push notification for it. Between the time the change was sent to you, lets say another edit was made to the file, with a changestamp of 101. Now changestamp 101 will invalidate changestamp 100.

One way to deal with this might be to get changes >= the change number that you get, and filter by fileId.

Also of note opening a file, even if you don't make any edits, updates it's lastViewed time, and thus generates a new change, thereby invalidating the older changestamp

Comment: Thanks, Eric. But it is so strange that the last change is invalidated and the second one from the end is still available. It only happened when uploading zip, rar, tar.gz. It works well when I only uploaded txt files.